# Recursively convert a given string to the number it represents

Tags: c++, recursion

Write a recursive function to convert a given string into the number it represents. That is input will be a numeric string that contains only numbers, you need to convert the string into corresponding integer and return the answer.

I only get the first digit of my string as the output. E.g "1234" as 1 or "231" as 2. Which makes me think there may be an error in my recursive function (the base case seems fine though) but I cant figure out what it is.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int lenght (char input[]){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0 ; input[i] != '\0' ; i++){
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

//helper
int stringToNumber(char input[], int start ) {
    int len = lenght(input);
    //base case
    if(start ==0){
        return int (input[start]) - 48;
    }
    int a = stringToNumber(input , start+1);
    int b = int(input[start]) - 48;

    int k = pow(10, len-1);
    return  k*b + a;
}

int stringToNumber(char input[]) {
    return stringToNumber(input, 0);
}

int main() {
    char input[50];
    cin >> input;
    cout << stringToNumber(input) << endl;
}
```

```
Sample Input 1 :
1231
Sample Output 1:
1231
What my code generates: 1
```

Comment: The best thing to learn at this point is how to debug your program. Debugging skills are critical to any software developer. If you step through the code, you can see what happens and that makes it easier to figure out what to change to make it work.

Comment: There is no end condition, you are increasing `start` with every call, but check if it is `0`. Also your start value is `0`, so the `if` is always true and it will return the first digit.

Comment: If I understand your requirements correctly, your basic algorithm is off.  You should not access the full set of digits in your main function, only the current calculated value and the next digit.  So, if your current value is `243` and you receive a `9`, you need to multiply `243` by `10` and add `9` to get `2439`.

Answer (score 1):

Converting string to decimal integer - is actually converting a number from decimal to binary form. I.e. each digit is a mod of 10.

I.e. for the 1234 it can be done done like `1 * 1000 + 2 * 100 + 3 * 10 + 4` 
or  `(1*10)+2, (12*10)+3, (123*10)+4`. Second algorithm can be implemented like next recursive function:

```
constexpr uintmax_t atou(const char* a,uintmax_t ret = 0) noexcept {
    return '\0' == *a ? ret : atou(a+1, (ret * 10) + ( *a - '0') );
}
```

i.e. you are scanning a string for digits, until '\0' end of line character (or [std::isspace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) for example), if more digits in the string multiply result on 10 and add the next digit to the result.

```
static_assert( 1234 == atou("1234"), "1234 expected" );
```

Comment: good answer. but wouldn't a "more natural" way would be to start from the right ? f("1234") = 10*f("123") + 4 ?  like "the value of the string is the rightmost char's value plus 10 times what is in front of it" ?,

Comment: Sure :) As well as  `atou(a+1, ( (ret << 3) + (ret << 1) ) + ( *a - '0') )` may work faster on some platforms.  Let's live it for student.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int convert(char c[]) {
    if (c[0]=='\0') {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int d = strlen(c) - 1;       
        int p = pow(10, d);       
        int k = int(c[0]) - 48; // ASCII value of '0' is 48
  
        return (k * p + convert(c + 1));
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    char c[n];
    cin >> c;

    cout << convert(c);  
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

public class solution {

```
public static int convertStringToInt(String input){
    // Write your code here
    if(input.length()<1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return input.charAt(input.length()-1)-'0'+(10*convertStringToInt(input.substring(0,input.length()-1)));
}
```

}